# Stackdriver Debugger doesn't capture snapshots

Tags: google-app-engine, debugging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I am using AppEngine, NodeJS (Standard), I have accepted the license agreements, and I am initializing the Debug Agent this way:

```
require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start({ allowExpressions: true });
```

I can see all the logs for my application in the Logs Viewer, all the requests are here.

When opening the Stackdriver Debugger, it recognizes what is the current source code running, and displays it. I try adding a few snapshots and logpoints, as basic as this:

```
if (true) logpoint("Hello World!")
```

It is waiting for hits, but obviously missing them. There are also no logs related to my logpoints. However, I can see the standard logs outputted by my app. Everything seems to work except the Stackdriver Debugger, even though it doesn't seem to complain either.

I have looked at everything and made sure everything was set up properly but I am not sure how to "debug the debugger" further.

Is it actually even working, and people are using it with NodeJS in Standard mode?

What can I check? Any way I can see errors related to the Debugger itself?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the „request” statement, how did you set up your project in Stackdriver Debugger for node.js? You may check [Setting Up Stackdriver Debugger for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/nodejs) as reference.

To reproduce this issue, one needs confidential information, such as details of your project and sample code. It is much easier to protect your information in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). You are encouraged to open a similar issue there.

Comment: For a NodeJS in Standard mode, the process is pretty easy. The Stackdriver is definitely initialized. But after that, the logpoints are not being hit. I wish the documentation about this was a bit denser, with more things to check. I opened an issue.