# Google Cloud Stackdriver Debug Agent: unable to set breakpoint in v8

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to set up Stackdriver debugger in node using the `@google-cloud/debug-agent` npm package. Seeing the following error when setting a snapshot breakpoint:

```
Unable to set breakpoint in v8
```

The debug agent is enabled for this version; however no request logs are appearing in the Stackdriver debug console. The panel shows startup logs only. Also, none of the logpoints are logging to the console.

Using app engine, node 10.16.0 and @google-cloud/debug-agent v4.0.1.

I have the following in `app.js`:

```
require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start({ allowExpressions: true });
```

And here's what I've added to `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/debug-agent": "^4.0.1",
    ...
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    ...
```

Since I was having an issue loading dependencies in Webpack, I added this line to the server webpack config:

```
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';

config = {
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the rest of the code you've added related to the debugger? It's a bit difficult to identify the issue without having a look on how you've set it up.

Comment: @siamsot I've edited the description. Not a lot of code changes to speak of, but I've added the change set for this. Please let me know if there's any other useful information I'm missing here. Thanks.

Comment: How do you try to take the snapshot? do you use at all the `-- debug` or `--debug-brk` flag?

Comment: I've tried setting the snapshot in the Stackdriver UI and using `gcloud beta debug snapshots create`. Same error. We're not using those flags on the deployed app (if that's what you're asking)

Comment: The snapshots are listed as active in the gcloud API, if that helps:


```gcloud beta debug snapshots create src/common/routes/index.js:98 --target [target]
 - id: 58efaef5b0579-a293-8578d
   location: src/common/routes/index.js:98
   status: ACTIVE
```

Comment: I would suggest you to do what was done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577220/stackdriver-debugger-doesnt-capture-snapshots) question as well because of the reasons mentioned there. You can open an issue through [this](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) link.

Comment: Filed an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138811568

Comment: Perfect! If there is anything from the answer that is useful for the community, please don't hesitate to add it as an answer to your question.