# Setting up google cloud debugger with webpack and typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, google-cloud-debugger

I'm trying to set up google cloud debugger in a project that compiles typescript using webpack to a single file with a source map. When I try to set a breakpoint in the debugger interface I'm getting an error "Unable to set breakpoint in v8".

The code I'm trying to debug is in a service that's in a subdirectory of the repo:

```
root
| package.json
| source-context.json
| - services
|   package.json
|   server.ts // Agent configured in here.
|   - build
|     server.js // File that is actually executed
|     server.js.map
```

The code I'm using to configure the agent is:

```js
require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start({
    serviceContext: {
      service: 'awesome-services',
      version: process.env.RELEASE_TAG || 'unknown',
      enableCanary: true,
    },
    sourceContext: require('../source-context.json')
  });
}
```

Is there some configuration I'm missing here or some way to get more information for debugging?

Comment: You can try to do some of the suggestions on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260878/google-cloud-stackdriver-debug-agent-unable-to-set-breakpoint-in-v8) as it has the same error message you encountered. Or you  can also check this [article](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/cannot-set-a-breakpoint-through-webpack/23533) though this one seemed to be browser specific. To also get the same setup, would you mind sharing the guide that you are using when setting up the cloud debugger?

Comment: I think I used multiple guides and read the client source code to get it set up, I'll check those links you posted.